# How to Calculate Confidence Intervals for Sampling Without Replacement

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation

The problem is estimating the size of a population through sampling *without* replacement. The items in the population are labeled with unbroken serial numbers. Thus, we are working with a discrete, finite, uniform distribution (not a normal distribution).

The sample size is given. We also know the maximum serial number among the items in the sample.

If I wish to perform interval estimation, i.e., calculate the confidence intervals with a level of confidence of $p$, what steps do I take?

Any references that may help in this regard would be greatly appreciated!